# Запуск двух категорий тестов

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

Подскажите как можно запустить тесты двух категорий через консоль и возможно ли это вообще?

Что бы запустить тесты определенно категории в терминале использую команду

```
 dotnet test --filter Category="var"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, судя по документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details , перечислите выражения через `&`:

```
dotnet test --filter Category="var" & Category="var1"
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность ! Я писал похоже но ошибка была в синтаксисе.

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк если ответ подходит, отметьте его как принятый